# Server doesn't follow TEMPLATE_DIRS path

Tags: python, django, templates

The path to my templates folder in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` looks like this:

`os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)) + '/static/templates/'`

When I run my server locally and open the page everything works fine and it detects the templates at `~/Documents/projects/clupus/static/templates`. Whenever I pull everything onto my server and access the URL it gives me this error:

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>   /home/ubuntu/public_html/clupus.com/clupus/templates/clupus/index.html
>   (File does not exist)

It's not following `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and is looking in the wrong directory. I've checked the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` value that's on the server and it matches that which I have locally. What's the issue?

**EDIT**

Rather embarrassingly there was nothing wrong with my code and I simply forgot to restart apache by doing `sudo service apache2 restart`. As to why my templates folder was inside static this is at the request of the front end developer. When I asked him why he said:

> the reason why they are inside it is because I'm trying to reference the templates in Javascript aswell because we are using shared templates between server and client

Comment: Is the /static/ url pointing to the static files directory?

Comment: Please bring your frontend developer here so that we can "-1" him :)

Answer (score 1):

First things first: static and templates are two very separate "things" and should not have anything in common - meaning that "templates" directory should be next to "static", not inside it.

There are by default two location where Django looks for template files:

- directory / directories specified in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`
- `templates` directory in each installed app (app that is in `INSTALLED_APPS`)

Your settings seem valid for the first case, so it's probably some simple error:

- Is `TEMPLATE_DIRS` still a tuple? `TEMPLATE_DIRS =( os.path.blah.blah, )`, the comma is necessary
- I don't see an exact mechanism that will cause problems when your `templates` directory is inside your `static` directory, but you should definitely move it out of there.
- Make sure the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting its [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders)

Answer (score 0):

The static url should point to the staticfiles directory. And why do you put templates under staticfiles? You may have it as a seperate folder in the main folder(along with manage.py)